# jQuery shortcut for element.innerHTML+=?

Tags: jquery, html, addition, innerhtml, shortcut

In native DOM search I can do:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML+= "text";
```

In jQuery as for today I must do:

```
$("#id").html($("#id").html()+"text");
```

(obviously I should cache the element, but it's not the point.)

So I wonder if there's a += shortcut for jQuery.

Comment: `.append()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**: `$("#id").append('text');`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought .append() only adds html element, but now I see it can add plain text to element as well.

Comment: Note: As mentioned in Paul Roub's answer, if your text contains HTML markup, you need to either HTML-encode it or use `document.createTextNode()` before appending.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to add a chunk of HTML to the end, you'd say:

```
$('#id').append( "<p>whatever</p>" );
```

if you want to add plain text (as above), or text that might *look* like HTML but shouldn't be interpreted that way:

```
$('#id').append( document.createTextNode( "text" ) );
```

Comment: You don't need `document.createTextNode`. `$("#id").append("text")` will work

Comment: Not if text looks HTML-ish, and you want it to stay text. For example, if you wanted the literal `<p>...</p>` text in my first example, you'll need a text node.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#id").html(function(i, o) {
  return o + "text";
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7ExW4/

See http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

If you want ease of use (sometimes the most important factor), use `.append()`.

If you want the best performance, use either `.innerHTML` or jQuery's `.html()`, or at least only call `.append()` only once.

As you can see from [this benchmark](http://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/19), calling `.append()` multiple times is very, very expensive. It is much faster to prepare what you want to add in a variable and then append/add that variable all at once.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightement.